# Usage of the Google Search API

Tags: c#, google-api

Is there any API which i can use in a WPF application to search Google?

The thing is:
Currently my team is searching for few files in Google and they do this alot, 
so I would like to build an application which will search for the files in Google and return the links.

E.g:
I am searching for the product `pentium 4 chips`.
Then they will search in Google for the documentation(PDF's basically) about `pentimum 4 chips`.
Following this, they will take the search results which matches the manufacturer website(e.g. `intel.com`)
and with the found PDF's they will continue their work.

I want to use the Google search API to get the details and give them the exact links or links which nearly match.

My problems:

- I am not finding a correct api.
- I am not sure how to use it.

Comment: NOTHING related to WPF!

Comment: I want to Create a WPF APPLICATION. SO.....

Comment: Why won't you use the google-api-dotnet-client?

Comment: i am trying there is no document or i am little dumb to use it. so facing problems

Comment: why the down vote what for.

Comment: The downvotes are for not doing any research.
There are many documents, take a look at the code.google dev site of the api for example - the first site I would look at.

Comment: i did and found all the things have no documentation. so asking here if any one has. i have and still tying to use the api's and i ma using .net 4 version. so checking for that.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter if its C# or WPF or WCF.
Frontend can be anything, you need to focus on logics.

Try this
http://googledotnet.codeplex.com/

Also
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxnetcom/thread/82da7a25-9f30-4d76-93dc-4acd1c2a938a

Comment: can you please let me know some examples of how it is used. i added to the project but not getting idea of how to use the api

Comment: You first try it with core programming i.e. C#, make it work in C# then migrate it to WPF.